# How can i add spring security based on roles authorization in spring boot where i have multiple entiites?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, user-roles

I study and am writing Spring Boot 3.0.4 project with MVC and want to add **Spring Security** to it. I want to create an electonic university diary, where all students and professors would be in database by from the beginning, and they need only login to this diary to get to their page, registration is not needed.

I don't understand how to add security for my project and controller, I need to add two Roles - **Student_Role** and **Professor_Role** and give them to Student and Professor accordingly. After that, i need to create security code so that the student can navigate through their part of the html pages as like in this lines:

```
.antMatchers("/student/**").hasRole("STUDENT")
.antMatchers("/professor/**").hasRole("PROFESSOR")
```

I don't find suitable examples on the Internet.
So I have two entities - **Student** and **Professor**. Here is code for them:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "first name cannot be empty")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "last name cannot be empty")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotBlank(message = "email cannot be empty")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotBlank(message = "password cannot be empty")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 16)
    private String password;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "professor")
public class Professor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "first name cannot be empty")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "last name cannot be empty")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotBlank(message = "email cannot be empty")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotBlank(message = "password cannot be empty")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    @NotBlank(message = "phone number cannot be empty")
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

And i also have JpaRepositories for them.
I don't understand how to add configuration and controller for login. I would be very grateful, if someone can help me with that

I tried to find example for solve this problem, but i don't find. I was trying to do this using LoginUser like buffer that has email and password fields
, but it's not actualy what i need, there is no spring security that i needed.
Here is my Controller and my login-page:

```
@Controller
public class LoginControllerV2 {

    StudentServiceImpl studentService;
    ProfessorServiceImpl professorService;

    @Autowired
    public LoginControllerV2(StudentServiceImpl studentService, ProfessorServiceImpl professorService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
        this.professorService = professorService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String menuPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginUser", new LoginUser());
        return "login-page";
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticateTheUser")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute LoginUser loginUser, Model model) {

        String page = "";
        String email = loginUser.getEmail();
        String password = loginUser.getPassword();
        
        if(studentService.findStudentByEmailAndPassword(email, password)!=null){
            Student student = studentService.findStudentByEmailAndPassword(email,password);
            model.addAttribute("student", student);
            page = "student-menu";
        } else if (professorService.findProfessorByEmailAndPassword(email, password)!=null){
            Professor professor = professorService.findProfessorByEmailAndPassword(email,password);
            model.addAttribute("professor", professor);
            page = "professor-menu";
        } 
        return page;
    }
}
```

And my thymeleaf page was:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Page</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/authenticateTheUser}" th:object="${loginUser}" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" th:field="*{password}" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think i need to create table Roles in database and create ManyToOne relashionship student-roles, professor-roles. But i don't know will it work and how to use it to configure spring security

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution which help you define rules and security policies dynamicly, is the ABAC (attributes based access control) method. Use one the best implementation:
https://sapl.io/

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow Spring boot security standards.
Email passwords of both Student & Professor should be in the same table.
Please check Spring Security basic projects and get started.